# Calculate and output difference of two pointers

Tags: c, pointers

The output of the following c program is 1. Can someone please explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int a = 5,b = 10,c;
    int *p = &a,*q = &b;
    c = p - q;
    printf("%d" , c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: It shall be `int main(void)` if no arguments are needed by `main()`.

Answer (score 7):

The program invokes undefined behavior. Pointer subtraction has to be done with pointers to elements of the same array.

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.5.6p9) "When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object [...]"

Answer (score 0):

The variables were allocated one after the other in the stack. Say on a machine with 4-byte sized integers the addresses may be say 1000 and 1004; the difference is 4 bytes; pointer arithmetic says that the difference should return the value in elements (not bytes), so number of elements (ints) between the address is 1 (integer).

However, this is valid only within the same array or one element past it, which isn't the case in your example, and thus is undefined.

**C++11 §5.7/6**:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted,
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements ... Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array
>   object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior
>   is undefined.

EDIT: Thanks ouah for making me lookup the C++ standard on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the differences in memory location of two successive stack-allocated pointers using `int` *pointer arithmetic* as your unit of measurement.

Technically the program behaviour is *undefined*. Rather pointless therefore to say any more.